# function as constructor parameter in python

Tags: python, constructor

Can a function be used as a parameter of the python `__init__` method?

What I'm trying to do is write a class for both the perceptron and logistic regression learning algorithms. As their training functions are very similar, and only really differ by the function used for prediction, it would be nice to be able to specify this function function at construction.

I hope this question hasn't been asked before (I've searched, haven't found anything; maybe I'm searching for the wrong topic). An example would be great. I'm not that familiar with `lambda`, so please provide some justification for any advanced python features. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Functions are first-class objects in Python, so you can pass them into any function you like as a parameter, including `__init__`.

```
def a():
    print("Hello!")

def b(fun):
    print("running fun")
    fun()
    print("all done")

b(a) # prints "running fun", then "Hello!", then "all done".
```

You can store them in classes just like any other variable:

```
class c(object):
    def __init__(self, fun):
        self.fun = fun
        self.fun()
```

`lambda` is just another way of writing a function, without having to store it in a variable. It can be used for defining functions on the fly, for example:

```
def d(fun, num):
    return fun(num)

def e(x):
    return x**2

d(lambda x: x**2, 7) # Returns 49
d(e) # Also returns 49
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, functions are first-class objects, and can be passed around as arguments.

Short demo:

```
>>> def foo(): print 'foo!'
... 
>>> bar = foo
>>> bar()
foo!
>>> def ham(eggs):
...     eggs()
... 
>>> ham(bar)
foo!
```

Note how I assigned `foo` to a new name `bar`, then called it both from `bar` and passed it to another function, where the parameter `egg` is called as a function.

Lambdas are just a short-form notation to create function objects. From Python's perspective, there is little difference:

```
>>> baz = lambda: 'baz'
>>> baz()
'baz'
>>> baz
<function <lambda> at 0x10f15c7d0>
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x10f15c6e0>
```

Both the `baz` lambda and the preceding `foo` function are function objects.